# How to implement nested columns ?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I am trying to re-develop a Delphi db Windows app with VS2010 C#.

In the Delphi app I made a nested column in my DBGrid component.

The text column ("Dummy Question") normally looks like this:

[image]

I then hacked the grid column so I can optionally display it like this:

[image]

How do I implement expandable/collapsible nested columns like this with Visual Studio 2010 C# controls?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at DevExpress datagrid - BandedGridView.

> Banded Grid Views allow you to arrange columns into bands. Visually,
>   bands are represented by their headers which are displayed over
>   headers of columns belonging to the band.

[BandedGridView Class](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraGridViewsBandedGridBandedGridViewtopic)